# Is it possible to do Dependent Types in Typed Racket?

Tags: programming-languages, typing, type-checking, dependent-types, lisp

Is it possible to use [Dependent Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) in the existing [Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/) implementation? (ie do they exist in it?)

Is it reasonably possible to implement a Dependent Types System using Typed Racket?

Comment: I think you need to clarify this question a bit: are you asking whether dependent types *exist* in Racket or weather it is possible to *add* them? If it's the former, then no (by most reasonable definitions of dependent types), and if it's the latter, then yes.

Comment: As cody notes, this question is unclear, and depending on what you meant the answer is either a not-very-interesting no or a not-very-interesting yes. Please flesh out this question so that we know what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependent Types in Racket are being worked on by Andrew Kent at Indiana University.

There is a set of [slides](https://github.com/pnwamk/talks/raw/762c22898cba7dfd9d21d37ca8e16e3f6b98bed5/iu-pl-wonks/wonks-apr2015.pdf). There is a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK0WtcppZuA).

Of interest, this [potentially also impacts Typed Clojure](https://twitter.com/ambrosebs/status/589259830881300480), which is strongly modeled on Typed Racket.

Comment: The slides link now returns 404. This link works: https://github.com/pnwamk/talks/raw/762c22898cba7dfd9d21d37ca8e16e3f6b98bed5/iu-pl-wonks/wonks-apr2015.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I think to "do dependent types" using contracts is already possible. Check https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-struct.html and look for "Checking Properties of Data Structures".

You could argue, that this is rather simulating the effect, than having it as part of the language. However, somewhere you'll need to write the code, which tells the interpreter/compiler what those dependencies are and in Racket you can do that with contracts.

Comment: I'm happy with the idea that macros in racket are 'extending the compiler'

Comment: @hawkeye Could you provide an answer to this question implementing dependent types with macros? (I do not doubt it is possible.)

Comment: The argument about whether macros extend the compiler are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/268091/15441 and you can put any piece of code into a macro - so the code that is used for dependent types can be put into a macro. That was the point I was making.